# robots.txt -- blank lines required between user-agent blocks, or optional?

Tags: user-agent, robots.txt

Seemingly conflicting descriptions given in authoritative documentation sources.

[A Standard for Robot Exclusion](https://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html):

('record' refers to each user-agent block)

> "The file consists of one or more records separated by one or more
>   **blank** lines (terminated by CR,CR/NL, or NL). Each record contains
>   lines of the form ...".

Google's [Robot.txt Specifications](https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_txt):

> "... Note the **optional use** of white-space and **empty lines** to improve
>   readability."

So -- *based on documentation that we have available to us* -- is this empty line here mandatory?

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /this-directory/

User-agent: DotBot
Disallow: /this-directory/
Disallow: /and-this-directory/
```

Or, is this OK?

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /this-directory/
User-agent: DotBot
Disallow: /this-directory/
Disallow: /and-this-directory/
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Comment: I don't agree with your assessment.  This question has nothing whatsoever to do with SEO.  This question is about the correct way to format a configuration that is used to properly administer a website, e.g., prevent bots that use up website resources, etc.

Comment: @JohnConde This is close to the first example of questions that **are** related to programming according to the post you linked to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google Robots.txt Parser and Matcher Library](https://github.com/google/robotstxt/blob/750aec7933648c816d6d5bb2f4fe5c30f2485ccf/robots.cc#L365) does not have special handling for blank lines. [Python urllib.robotparser](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/19be85c76503535c101b38194d282187de0ff631/Lib/urllib/robotparser.py#L96) always interprets blank lines as the start of a new record, although they are not strictly required and the parser also recognizes a `User-Agent:` as one. Therefore, both of your configurations would work fine with either parser.

This, however, is specific to the two prominent `robots.txt` parser; you should still write it in the most *common* and *unambiguous* way possible to deal with badly written custom parsers.

Answer (score 2):

Best not to have any blank lines. I was having problems with my robots.txt file and everything worked fine AFTER I removed all blank lines.